# Access Scope of elements in page object model

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am working on to automate a form to create a profile. While doing that I observed a something i need to understand. Please look at the code below and if it would be great if anyone can explain the reason behind this.

I am using page object for my project.
I have selectors defined under elements and i am accessing the elements/selectors in the functions down below.

I am not able to access the elements inside the function for the below code

For the this.api.perform function when I try to access the element(subjectGenderFemale) to click on it, it errors out with the error "ERROR: Unable to locate element: "@subjectGenderFemale" using: css selector". So i had to access it with the actual selector 'input[value="F"]'. Please refer to the code below @ .api.perform.

```
'use strict';
var assert = require('assert');

var subjectJSON = require('../../../e2e/data/subjectData.json');

module.exports = {
   elements: {
    newSubjectButton: {
      selector: '.btn.btn--primary'
},
subjectFirstName: {
  selector: 'input[name^="first_name"]'
},
subjectLastName: {
  selector: 'input[name^="last_name"]'
},
subjectDateOfBirth: {
  selector: 'input[name^="date_of_birth"]'
},
subjectGenderFemale: {
  selector: 'input[value="F"]'
},
subjectGenderMale: {
  selector: 'input[value="M"]'
},
submitButton: {
  selector: '.col.col-sm-offset-2.col-sm-8>div>form>button'
}
  },
  commands: [{
openCreateSubjectForm: function() {
  return this
    .waitForElementPresent('@newSubjectButton', 1000)
    //the below href needs to change to proper element
    .click('a[href="/subject/create"]')
},
populateSubjectForm: function() {
  return this
  .setValue('@subjectFirstName', subjectJSON["createSubject"]["firstName"])
  .setValue('@subjectLastName', subjectJSON["createSubject"]["lastName"])
  .setValue('@subjectDateOfBirth', subjectJSON["createSubject"]["dateOfBirth"])
  .api.perform(function() {
    if (subjectJSON["createSubject"]["gender"]=="F") {
      this.api.click('input[value="F"]')
    }else if (subjectJSON["createSubject"]["gender"]=="M") {
      this.api.click('input[value="M"]')
    }else if (subjectJSON["createSubject"]["gender"]=="Both") {
      this.api.click('input[value="Both"]')
    }else {
      this.api.click('input[value="No preference"]')
    }
  })
},
submitCreateSubjectForm: function() {
  return this.click('@submitButton');
 }
}]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

i got around this problem by accessing it via `this.elements.subjectGenderFemale.selector`